# How to configure Mulesoft runtime server in Eclipse (Mulesoft plugin)?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, esb

I have installed Mulesoft plugin in Eclipse, but while creating new project I found there is not runtime server running. How could I configure runtime server for Mulesoft plugin in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Help > Install New Software > Work with >> Add

Add the MuleSoft ESB Runtimes http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes

You Should see AnyPoint Studio Community Runtimes and Enterprise as well.

Depending on what versions and editions you select, you can them configure.

Answer (score 0):

The Anypoint Plugin for Eclipse is not much like the AnyPoint standalone, you must install the Runtimes:

Help > Install New Software > Work with >> Add

Add the MuleSoft ESB Runtimes http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes

You Should see AnyPoint Studio Community Runtimes and Enterprise as well

Depending on what versions and editions you select, you can them configure the Server Runtimes in your mule-project.xml

Answer (score 0):

You may want to download Mule Anypoint Studio [here](https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/studio). This Studio is an IDE which makes easy developing Mule applications and it accelerates developer productivity. So, IMHO, instead of installing Anypoint plugin on Eclipse, it would be better to download Anypoint Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It better to go with AnyPoint Studio rather than ecplise, here in anypoint studio directly you will be provided with Runtime.

In Anypoint studio if you want to add runtime esb you need to go 
Help--> Install New Software--> Mule ESB Runtimes for Anypoint Studio - http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes/
[image help to see the runtime available details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYade.png)

after that in your project you can select which version you want to work on.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to install latest Anypoint platform from Mulesoft site and try to install this then automatically what ever the plugins or updates will be added automatically

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected Anypoint Studio while installing Mulesoft plugin. This will install Mule Runtime as well. If no then install Mule Runtime first. After that click on mule-project.xml and select Mule Runtime version and run mules project.

Answer (score 0):

while installing Mulesoft plugin, that will install Mule Runtime as well. If we dont install Mule Runtime first, then click on mule-project.xml and select Mule Runtime version and run mules project.